# Load .txt into a FlowDocumentScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, load, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I am dynamically creating FlowDocumentScrollViewer how do I open .txt file in FlowDocumentScrollViewer?
I used this when I had richtextbox, but how do I do the same in FlowDocumentScrollViewer?

```
fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

range = new TextRange(mcRTB.Document.ContentStart, mcRTB.Document.ContentEnd);
                        range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Text);
```

Comment: You don't.  You display a FlowDocument in FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

Comment: Can you please help me with a code snippet for the same?

Comment: There is no same. A FlowDocumentScrollViewer does not display straight text.  There are examples on msdn.microsoft.com on how to create a FlowDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
FlowDocumentScrollViewer flowDocumentSV = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer();


                    try
                    {
                        fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                        FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();

                        range = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);

                        range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Text);
                        flowDocScrollViewer.Document = flowDocument;
}
```